# Tensorflow: Is there any difference between "sess = tf.Session()" and "with tf.Session() as sess:"?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any difference between using:

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

vs.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

I ask because I have a more specific example of the above, using a supervised session, where:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=logdir, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
   checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(a.checkpoint)
   restore_saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
```

correctly loads a checkpoint, but the following:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=logdir, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=None)
sess = sv.managed_session()
checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(a.checkpoint)
restore_saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
```

results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-24404191b942>", line 59, in <module>
restore_saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)

File "C:\Users\____\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1685, in restore
sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,

AttributeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'run'
```

where the session object 'sess' appears as:

```
<contextlib._GeneratorContextManager at 0x1b06ee57550>
```

Would really appreciate if someone could explain what's going on.  Thanks!

Comment: `tf.Session` is a class so `tf.Session()` returns a object with methods including `run`. `tf.train.Supervisor` is also a class which has a method `managed_session()` that returns a context manager. The context manager is typically used with `with`.